# How can I plot the sum of values (rather than the count) using seaborn violinplot?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

I have a data set with various quantities which I would like to make a violin plot of using seaborn. However, instead of visualizing the COUNT of occurrences of all of the quantities I'd like to display the SUM of the quantities.

For example, if I have a data set like this...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'quantity':[1,1,1,4]})
sns.violinplot(data=df)
```

[Actual Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiIwn.png)

I really want it to display something like this...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'quantity':[1,1,1,4,4,4,4]})
sns.violinplot(data=df)
```

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NbRy.png)

My data set is around 500k values ranging between 1 and 10k so its not possible to transform the data as above (ie [1,1,2,3] -> [1,1,2,2,3,3,3]).

I know I could do something like this below to get the values I want and then plot with a bar plot or something...

```
df.quantity.value_counts() * df.quantity.value_counts().index
```

however, I really like seaborns violin plot and the ability to pair it with catplot so if anyone knows a way to do this in seaborn I'd be very grateful.

Comment: The `kdeplot` (drawing half a violin) has a `weigths=` parameter: `sns.kdeplot(data=df, y='quantity', weights='quantity', fill=True)`. But `violinplot` doesn't seem to work with such parameter.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC! I end up using kdeplot on multiple axes created through matplotlib.pyplot (rather than FacetGrid) and it did the job. I've still never been able to figure out how FacetGrid works when you need to pass additional arguments to it (ie weights)!